# Python issue, trying to great a simple Death counter

Tags: python, pygame

New getting into python / pygame. Trying to make a death counter for my twitch stream.

I'm going to eventually make it use a GUI, but for now I just want it to run in the back ground and on keypress input from the 1 Key add a +1 to the number in the file.  2 resets that number to 0.

Getting an error on line 19.

```
  File "C:/Python27/Deathcounter.py", line 19, in <module>
    if event.key == pygame.K_1:
AttributeError: event member not defined
```

Also, I'm certain I've overcomplicated this process as I always do.I

```
# Death Counter
import pygame, sys
import pygame.locals

# Variables
deathcount = float(0)

pygame.init()
BLACK = (0,0,0)
WIDTH = 320
HEIGHT = 260
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), 0, 32)

windowSurface.fill(BLACK)

while True:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.key == pygame.K_1:
            with open("deathcounter.txt", "rt") as in_file:
                deathcount = in_file.read()
                deathcount = deathcount + 1
            with open("deathcounter.txt", "wt") as out_file:
                out_file.write(deathcount)
        if event.key == pygame.K_2:
            deathcount = 0
            with open("deathcounter.txt", "wt") as out_file:
                out_file.write(deathcount)

pass
if event.type == QUIT:
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Thanks for the advice / help.

Comment: What is pygame.K_1 ? Is it a method inside the class pygame ? You can only access K_1 if it's declared inside the module/class whose name is pygame.

Comment: ok, I misunderstood the tutorial. K_1 was supposed to represent the 1 Key on the keyboard as in K = Keyboard . 1 = The 1 Key

Answer (score 0):

Not all event have a key attribute, this is why you got this error.

Also first time you open your file for reading, this one didn t exist, so it ll raise an exception.

```
# Death Counter
import pygame
import sys
import pygame.locals

# Variables
deathcount = float(0)

pygame.init()
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WIDTH = 320
HEIGHT = 260
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), 0, 32)

windowSurface.fill(BLACK)

while True:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if hasattr(event, 'key'):
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                try:
                    with open("deathcounter.txt", "r") as in_file:
                        deathcount = int(in_file.read())
                        deathcount = deathcount + 1
                except (IOError, ValueError), err:
                    print err
                    deathcount = 0
                with open("deathcounter.txt", "w") as out_file:
                    out_file.write(str(deathcount))
            if event.key == pygame.K_2:
                deathcount = 0
                with open("deathcounter.txt", "w") as out_file:
                    out_file.write(str(deathcount))

pass
if event.type == pygame.event.QUIT:
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

For informations, using PyGame to catch key in background isn t the good fw to use, as it ll require that pygame windows have the active focus. So if you are using windows, i ll suggest you to take a look at this example which use PyHook : https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/229564/python-keylogger, else on linux, look to python x11 library